# Why isn't my UIScrollView scrolling fully?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I dont know why my UIScroll view doesn't work. I am just learning iOS development and when I covered UIScrollView, I had problems in scrolling.

I created a new project just to check the scroll, but I had no luck. I'm using the iOS 6.1 simulator with Xcode 4.6.2.

This is my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CDViewController12 : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;
}


@end

and my .m file

#import "CDViewController12.h"

@interface CDViewController12 ()

@end

@implementation CDViewController12

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(250, 2000);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [scroll release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try deactivating the auto layout property. 
In the file inspector uncheck the box "Use AutoLayout"

hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the the size of the scroll view is not larger than the size of the parent view.